# Improve query performance with index

Tags: mysql, index

I am looking to create an index for a database to acheive better performance.
I am using this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.* FROM current_order
AS t1 LEFT JOIN
receipt AS t2 USING (paper_id,subscriber_id)
WHERE t2.id NOT IN (SELECT id
FROM receipt WHERE paid_till_date > Now())
UNION
SELECT current_order.* FROM receipt RIGHT JOIN
current_order USING (paper_id, subscriber_id)
Where receipt.id IS NULL ORDER BY
subscriber_id, paper_id
```

Tables are:

```
 PAPER
    id
    name

 SUBSCRIBER
    id
    name
    address
    suburb
    state
    postcode
    round_id

 CURRENT ORDER
    paper_id
    subscriber_id

 ROUND
    id
    name
    paperboy

 RECEIPT
    id
    receipt_date
    paid_till_date
    paper_id
    subscriber_id
```

I understand that primary keys are already indexed, and that i should use an index where WHERE clauses and ORDER BY clauses are used frequently. So i'm assuming that the subscribers Name would be a good one to index?
And also the receipt date?

Any tips appreciated

Comment: i think the column pepr_id in RECEIPT should be paper_id and also "receipt" in the last line should be "receipt". i wanted to edit the post but was not able to convince the system that I am a human being.

Comment: is receipt.id a primary key and paid_till_date a "not null" column?

Comment: receipt.id is a primary key, but paid_till_date is not a "not null" field

Comment: I think  
    `SELECT DISTINCT t1.* FROM current_order  
    AS t1 LEFT JOIN  
    receipt AS t2 USING (paper_id,subscriber_id)  
    WHERE t2.id NOT IN (SELECT id  
    FROM receipt WHERE paid_till_date > Now())`

( the first part of your union) is equivalent to  


    `SELECT DISTINCT t1.* FROM current_order  
    AS t1 LEFT JOIN  
    receipt AS t2 USING (paper_id,subscriber_id)  
    WHERE (paid_till_date > Now()) or pid_till_now is null` 

is this true?

Comment: I think the second part of your union (all current_order where  no receip exists) is contained in the first query because then there is no receipt with paid_till_date > Now(). Is this true?

Comment: Do you have a compound index on `(subscriber, paper_id)`, on both tables?

Comment: No, the only indexes i have so far are the ones that would have been automatically created with the primary keys

Comment: IF you login here with the same information you logged into your [so] account the two will be linked ...

Answer (score 2):

The original query

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.* 
  FROM current_order AS t1 
    LEFT JOIN receipt AS t2 USING (paper_id,subscriber_id)
  WHERE t2.id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
      FROM receipt 
      WHERE paid_till_date > Now()
    )
UNION
  SELECT current_order.* 
    FROM receipt 
      RIGHT JOIN current_order USING (paper_id, subscriber_id)
    WHERE receipt.id IS NULL 
    ORDER BY subscriber_id, paper_id
```

is more complex than necessary.

The base tables are

```
CURRENT ORDER
  paper_id
  subscriber_id
```

and

```
RECEIPT
  id
  receipt_date
  paid_till_date
  paper_id
  subscriber_id
```

The OP stated that `receipt.id` is a primary key and I think that `(paper_id,subscriber_id)` is the primary key of `current order`.

Both queries

```
SELECT t1.* 
  FROM current_order AS t1 
    LEFT JOIN receipt AS t2 USING (paper_id,subscriber_id)
  WHERE t2.id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
      FROM receipt 
      WHERE paid_till_date > Now()
    )
```

and

```
SELECT t1.* 
  FROM current_order AS t1 
    LEFT JOIN receipt AS t2 USING (paper_id,subscriber_id)
  WHERE paid_till_date <= Now()
    or paid_till_date  is NULL
```

are equivalent: The resultset f both queries contains exactly the following tuples:

```
all tuples from current_order where there is a RECEIPT with the same (paper_id,subscriber_id) and paid_till_date <= Now()
all tuples from current_order where there is a RECEIPT with the same (paper_id,subscriber_id) and paid_till_date is NULL
all tuples from current_order where there is no RECEIPT with the same (paper_id,subscriber_id) (and therefore paid_till_date  is NULL)
```

Therefore the queries are equivalent. And they are also equivalent if an DISTINCT is added to the select clause.

The resultset of the query

```
  SELECT current_order.* 
    FROM receipt 
      RIGHT JOIN current_order USING (paper_id, subscriber_id)
    WHERE receipt.id IS NULL 
    ORDER BY subscriber_id, paper_id
```

contains the following tuples

```
all tuples from current_order where there is no RECEIPT with the same (paper_id,subscriber_id) (and therefore receipt.id is NULL)
```

So the original query can be changed to the simpler query

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.* 
  FROM current_order AS t1 
    LEFT JOIN receipt AS t2 USING (paper_id,subscriber_id)
  WHERE paid_till_date <= Now()
    or paid_till_date  is NULL
```

Perhaps an index on (paper_id,subscriber_id,paid_till_date) will be usefull. The query uses only columns found in the index (receipt.id is not used anymore). An Index on (paper_id,subscriber_id) of "current order" already exists because this is the primary key.